# Always thrown UnauthorizedAccessException when using DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl Method (C#, Windows 10)

Tags: c#

I creating an application that needs access to list the content (subdirectories, files) of directories (tree structure). There are some directories that cannot be accessed by an ordinary user. In order to get access to **every** directory and its content, I tried to run the application as administrator (creating a manifest file for the application) and then as system (creating the application as a service). There are directories in which the administrator doesn't have access. Also, there are directories in which the system doesn't have access. The number of the directories which are not accessible for the administrator is bigger than the number of the directories which are not accessible for the system.

Seeing that that both accounts have the same problem, I have chosen to work with the administrator account and I have tried to give the administrator the needed permissions in order to enter the forbidden folders. I have given the administrator the privilege to list the content of these directories (**this worked for some of them, but for others it didn't work => the reason for this question**). This is my code (in order to write the code, I have read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8):

```
  DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
  DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
   dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"Administrators",
                       FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, AccessControlType.Allow));
  dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

The code fails at the second line: the GetAccessControl method. There is thrown the UnauthorizedAccessException. In the same article I have read that this exception may have the following causes:

*• The current process does not have access to open the directory.*

*• The directory is read-only.*

*• This operation is not supported on the current platform.*

*• The caller does not have the required permission.*

For some of the directories, the owner is the ordinary user. The method fails even when running with the ordinary user account.
I have put the code above in the service app, but the method fails for the system account, too.

I tried to change the owner of the folders into administrator, but I have found in some examples (on SO and not only) that I need to use the same method (GetAccessControl) that always throws the exception. All of the directories for which the exception is thrown are **not** read-only.

For example, the administrator did not have access into SystemVolumeInformation. After applying the above code (run as administrator), the application could enter the folder and read a part of the content. Inside that folder, there is another folder: AadRecoveryPasswordDelete. When applying the code to the AadRecoveryPasswordDelete subfolder, there is thrown the exception UnauthorizedAccessException. If I run the application as the ordinary user: access is denied into SystemVolumeInformation folder for the user; after applying the above code (run as the ordinary user), the application fails at GetAccessControl method.

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019.

**Why is always thrown this exception? How can I enter the folders and list their content?**

Comment: Folders like the SystemVolumeInformation are not accessible using this API. You shouldn't be trying to access them, least of all by messing with the  permissions on them. You could break the whole Windows installation. Why are you trying to read the contents of system folders anyway?

Comment: I have to create the tree of subdirectories and files starting from a root directory. The tree has to contain **all** of the subdirectories and files, thus my app needs to get permission to every folder.